# How to run an Azure DevOps pipeline from code?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have been working with an Azure DevOps release definition and triggering it from some C# code:

```
var releaseClient = VssConnection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient>();

return await releaseClient.CreateReleaseAsync(
    _releaseDefinitionId,
    $"Release run for {build.BuildNumber}",
    build.Definition.Name,
    build.Id,
    new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "InputVariable1", _value1 },
        { "InputVariable2", _value2 },
        { "DatabaseConnectionString", "xxxxxxx" }
    });
```

I've now converted that release definition to a pure YAML pipeline - is there any way to trigger the running of that pipeline from C#?

Thanks!

Comment: Yaml pipelines translate to Builds. So I think you need to queue  a new build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can trigger YAML build in this way:

```cs
var credential = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT");
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/"), credential);
var buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

var projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
var project = projectClient.GetProject("DevOps Manual").Result;
Console.WriteLine(project.Name);

var definition = buildClient.GetDefinitionAsync("DevOps Manual", 48).Result;

Console.WriteLine(definition.Name);

var build = new Build()
{
    Definition = definition,
    Project = project
};
string _value1 = "someStr1";
string _value2 = "someStr2";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "InputVariable1", _value1 }, { "InputVariable2", _value2 }, { "DatabaseConnectionString", "xxxxx" } };
build.Parameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);

buildClient.QueueBuildAsync(build).Wait();
```

Comment: parameters are not passed to YAML pipelines. I get **Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings. A value for the 'InputVariable1' parameter must be provided.** Any idea why?

Comment: Without information how your pipeline looks like it would be difficult to help you. Please create a new question, share with us your pipeline thus we should be able to help you.

Comment: I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933985/queue-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-from-code-does-not-accept-parameters

Comment: Krzysztof Madej  help would be appreciated